# How can I integrate pug templating engine in angular using angular cli?

Tags: angular, pug

Currently I'm working on angular project that uses HTML. Now I want to integrate Pug templating engine in my project. How can I integrate Pug in my Angular project using AngularCLI? Any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

For Angular8 you can run `ng add ng-cli-pug-loader@0.2`.
For Angular6+ run `ng add ng-cli-pug-loader`.
If your want to update old project to angular8, remove your `node_modules` and 
reinstall all package.
[ng-cli-pug-loader](https://github.com/danguilherme/ng-cli-pug-loader)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know Angular uses its own html parser, looks like your task doens't make a sense. I don't see any reason to intergate pug there.